# Weird Compile Error In Swift When Using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, release

I've seen a number of questions about this, but I'm still confused as hell about what is happening.

I **HATE** blaming the language or compiler, but, with Swift, it's a definite possibility.

When I build and run in debug mode, all is right with the world.

However, when I compile in release mode, the compiler pukes with this error:

```
"Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither"...Yadda, yadda
```

The offending line appears to be this one:

```
let lastURI:AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(s_currentURIKey)
```

[It's right here](https://bitbucket.org/bmlt/bmltadmin/src/f0b8c75c469097d4a4ac4c027198adea34a3ad6e/BMLTAdmin/BMLTAdminConnectViewController.swift?at=master#cl-636), if you want to follow along in your textbook (It's an open-source project).

If I comment out this line (and the 7 lines below it), then the sun shines, and birds tweet happily. If I leave it in, then dark clouds and swarms of orcs spew forth from Mordor.

In order to make it fail, I simply run the profiler, which compiles in release mode.

Anyone have any experience with this kind of agita?

All the other versions of this issue tend to resolve to issues with specific Cocoa API calls. It's not clear to me whether or not the user is at fault.

I really want it to be my fault, which means there's something I can do about it.

If it isn't my fault, then I need to file a RADAR issue, and grow a long gray beard before I can test this app with a profiler.

It will be a while before it will be ready for release, but I like to test my apps in release mode very early on.

Comment: Wow, the really compiler pukes "Yadda, yadda"? Is that a technical term? While that is cute an entire error message might be more helpful.

Comment: you should not use `valueForKey` - use `objectForKey`.

Comment: You probably should not use `NSUserDefaults`. As you can see you have little control over it. Create a Data Model class and use NSArchiver and you have full control and compiler syntax checking.

Comment: Yeah, my computer is infected by the DUDE virus. ;) I am continuing to look at this. Using objectForKey seems to have addressed this one, but I am getting the failure again, so I am playing whack-a-mole...

Comment: NSUserDefaults is extremely easy to use. However, if it don't work properly, then I'll use something that takes a bit more work. Not the end of the world (unless I am forced to use PoorData). This is whacky. I'll keep whacking them little suckers and report back what I find.

Comment: I did put it in a test app and it compiled with no issue. Is it a compile or RT error?

Comment: While "extremely easy to use" is one aspect if we want to be professionals and/or call ourselves engineers we must go with safe and secure practices as a first priority. If we just want to have fun OK, go for it.

Comment: Yo. Don't be insulting. I've always done it the hard way before (look at my other projects). This was the first time I tried NSUserDefaults. I did it because A) I like the idea of it being shared between devices and B) Ray Wenderlich used it in a tutorial, so I figgered I'd give it a try.

Comment: @zaph why should one not use NSUserDefaults? Makes absolutely not sense to me.

Comment: @Thomas Kilian It works fine on its own, or in a playground. I'm also kinda guessing as to which line is causing it. The app is still pretty nascent, but there's a fair bit of code written already. As I said, it only seems to be an issue in release mode.

Comment: Try simply moving the line up a bit (just a guess). Swift error messages are - hmpfff

Comment: Yeah, there's something more going on. I played around with it, and now I keep getting the error. I shouldn't waste y'all's time until I've stomped around this minefield a bit longer...

Comment: OK. Found a line that seems to be more solidly causing the issue. Has nothing at all to do with NSUserDefaults. I was chasing a will o' the wisp.

Comment: I fixed it. It was because I was appending to an array of tuples, using +=. D'oh!

Comment: As I said: Swift error messages. You can wipe your butt with them :-(

Comment: @ThomasKilian `NSUserDefaults` uses strings for a key so there is no type checking and another class can easily to s=choose to =use the same key. All methods and classes share `NSUserDefaults` so there is no isolation between classes. It supports only a limited set of types and this is a particular problem with Swift. It was designed so support a limited amount of data namely UserDefaults in OS X. It is saved in a single plist that must be read by the app in entirety and saved in entirety. It is stored un-protected in the Library directory and is easy accessed and compromised.

Comment: @ThomasKilian There is no initialization of all elements used by a class as would be the case NSArchiver so if one is testing a values such as true or false (YES or NO) one first has to check if the values exists and at access tie the code needs to know the default value which it shouldn't have to.

Comment: @MAGNAWS Note that I did not exclude myself from y rant about professionalism. Typically a professional has to pass an industry or government written test, show several years of experience under a certified professional and attend continuing education yearly. Example: CISSP required five years 100% work in the domain under the supervision of certified CISSP. The test is a six hour proctored test. Typically the prior book based study is over 100 hours. 40 hours of approved continuing education is required per year. Very few developers come close. But we can all aim to work as professionals.

Comment: @zaph Appreciate your explanation. I'm aware of those drawbacks but for what it was designed it looks ok (as long as you know what you deal with). Let's leave it at that point. Thanks  and cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Here's what I found out.

I had an array of tuples as a variable:

```
var arrayOfTuples:[(greeting: String, query: String)]! = []
```

I was appending to it using +=, and a single element array, like so:

```
arrayOfTuples += [(greeting: "HI", query: "HOWAYA")]
```

This worked and compiled fine in debug mode, but caused that strange error in release mode.

I fixed it it by replacing "+=" with ".append()", like so:

```
arrayOfTuples.append((greeting: "HI", query: "HOWAYA"))
```

Go figure. In any case, append was more appropriate, so good coding practice prevails.